# Is new DEV API missing data?

Tags: api, amadeus

After getting a valid token...

This query does not work on the new DEV API.

```
curl -k https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=RDU&destination=MKE&departureDate=2019-08-02&adults=2&children=1&includeAirlines=F9&nonStop=true&max=50
```

I get:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 404,
      "code": 1797,
      "title": "NOT FOUND",
      "detail": "No itinerary found for requested segment 1",
      "source": {
        "parameter": "origin/destination/date(s) combination"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I remove the nonStop and include airlines the query runs with nonstop results.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the test environment, in this one we offer a subset of our data.
If you want to have access to the full content you will need to move to production.

I tested your request in production and it works

Comment: Is it documented TEST is now a subset?

Comment: You can find the explanation here: https://developers.amadeus.com/pricing. The content we have in the test environment is published here: https://github.com/amadeus4dev/hackathon-starter#datasets and will very soon be published on our portal.

Comment: Cool. The answers my question. Thanks!